# Deregister Scripts Wordpress (wp-includes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

No frontend do wordpress é carregado uma leva de scripts que estão inclusos no diretório *wp/includes*. Tais como:

```
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/mouse.min.js
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/sortable.min.js
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/tabs.min.js
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/accordion.min.js
```

É possível (e como) fazer o **wp_deregister_script()** neles?

***Nota:*** Sei que eles são necessários para o wp-admin, por isso poderemos utilizar o:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) wp_deregister_script('script_nome');
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma documentação referente aos scripts carregado por padrão pelo WordPress, ela pode ser conferida em [lista de scripts do wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress).

Desta forma basta utilizar o código padrão para fazer o deregister do script, tendo como exemplo o *"tabs.min.js"* que se chama *"jquery-ui-tabs"*.

> wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-tabs');